# Validatior Async Angular 5 no me muestra mensajes

Tags: typescript, angular, angular5

hola soy nuevo en angular tengo la versión 5 y estoy tratando de hacer una validación que verifique si un dato esta registrado en al base de datos el detalles esta es que cuando se ejecuta la validación no se interpreta el mensaje de error creo que es un problema de como el servicio devuelve la validación este es el codigo que estoy usado.

```
rutExistValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    return this.apiValiRut(control.value).subscribe(data => {
       this.datos = data;
       if (this.datos.process) {
         return { 'rutExist': { value: control.value } };
       }
    });
  }
}
```

y el error se muestra así.

```
<div *ngIf="form.controls['rut'].errors.rutExist">
  * este rut ya existe
</div>
```

Si alguien puede orientar seria de mucha ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puesto que el validador es asíncrono, no puede devolver otra cosa que no sea un Observable. Tal y como lo tienes escrito no funciona, debería ser algo como:

```
rutExistValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<[key: string]: any }> => 
    this.apiValiRut(control.value).map(data => {
       if (data.process) {
         return { 'rutExist': { value: control.value } };
       }
       return null;
    });
  }
}
```

Y, cuando lo asignes como validador al *form*, tienes que hacer un `.bind(this)` para que pueda llamar a tu método `apiValiRut`. Además, los validadores asíncronos se declaran en un array aparte de los validadores síncronos: `formBuilder.group({ rut: ['',[<validadores>],[<validadores asincronos>]`

Comment: Gracias amigo resolvi el problema con la solucion que me enviaste.